# Send back more than one Param to ActionMethod based on href definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this href defined in my markup:

```
    foreach (Car car in Model.Cars)
    {
        <p><a href="/Admin/Car/@car.Name/Url/">@car.Name</a></p>
    }
```

The route actually is wired to run an action method that expects 3 parameters:

```
public string GetCarUrl(int dealerId, string carName, int userId)
```

The route looks like this:

```
context.MapRoute("AdminLessonsDownloadFile", ""/Admin/Car/{carName}/Url/", new { controller = "Car", action = "GetCarUrl", carName= UrlParameter.Optional });
```

How do I send in the dealerId and userId along with the fileName that I specify in the url (href)?

Comment: Is dealerId and userId part of your model?

Comment: I don't see the model being passed for click of hyperlinks probably because it's not a postback..it just is a redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route has to include then, as it does carName.  Assuming the rest of your routing works, try this:

```
context.MapRoute("AdminLessonsDownloadFile", 
    ""/Admin/Car/{carName}/{dealerId}/{userId}", 
    new { controller = "Car", action = "GetCarUrl", carName= UrlParameter.Optional, dealerId = UrlParameter.Optional, userId=UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I want to know how I can send back other params to the actionmethod than just CarName when the user clicks the hyperlink.  I'd like to store it in the ViewModel but I don't  think that the model instance is passed back with hyperlinks as you're not doing a form submit, rather a redirect?

Comment: I don't want to expose all these in the url, some I want to hide in the model.

Comment: do the others have to be defined as UrlParameter.Optional ...for the dealerId and userId for the actionmethod to pick it up or can I just leave optional out completely of all 3 are required to be sent to the action method?  I didn't know if you always have to have optional defined for each one of the placeholders in MVC in order for the actionmethod to pick it up from the route.

Comment: My apologies: I left dealerId and UserId out of part of the route declaration (see above correction).  I've fixed that.  If the hyperlink is functioning as a hyperlink (and taking the user to its href), then the data more or less has to be in the URL, though I suppose it could be placed in session or cookie.  If clicking the link prompts an AJAX action, information could be submitted to a service call via the post method, keeping them from the URL.  Perhaps I'm not understanding the context of what you're doing.

Comment: looks like the answer is yes, you must have optional defined for every placeholder regardless if it's required internally by the action method, that is totally seperate from the requriement of the action method - to - optional param defined...which must be there for the action method to know that those params exist in the url.  DUH.  shit it's coming back to me.

Comment: Honestly, requiring valid values is something I've always handled in the controller, so I'd say that you test the values in the controller and redirect the response from within the controller if the parameters are invalid.  I don't actually know if you can set them to something other than UrlParameter.Optional.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
foreach (Car car in Model.Cars)
{
    <p><a href="/Admin/Car/@car.Name/Url/?@car.DealerId&@car.UserId">@car.Name</a></p>
}
```

Comment: what if you don't want it exposed in the url?  Can they somehow be sent to a controller action via like some collection that is carried with the request other than specifying a ViewModel as the expected param which could also contain that?

Comment: I guess I should just probably pass the viewmodel back to the controller and add in whatever fields I need in the viewmodel

Comment: crap this is a hyperlink, it's not gonna post back the model with it if I'm doing just a redirect

Comment: If you do not want these exposed to the URL, you have another option to store them within the anchor tag like this - <a href="" data-dealerid="@car.DealerId" data-userid="@car.UserId">...</a> - this is a supported format for custom tag attributes in HTML5. But I suppose this is not going to be very useful since you're not submitting the page via a button...I think your best bet is to submit the @car.CarId with the URL and then retrieve the rest of the info (dealer, car name, user, etc) in your controller.